# Qué podria estar pasando en esta página de woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Se me está presentando un problema que no tengo ni idea como arreglarlo ya que yo lo que hice fue instalar el woocommerce y la plantilla pero al momento de ir a pagar la página de checkout se me ve horrible.

[triple.cl](https://triple.cl)

Al momento de pagar la página se ve así:

[image: Pagar Orden de Compras]

Y nunca toqué ni css ni html ni nada pero la página se ve dañada, que podría ser? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que hay problema con los estilos css. Seguramente en algun momento se eliminan y no se añaden o algún css sobreescribe clases de otro que WooCommerce usa.

- Probaría a cambiar el theme de la página para ver si es problema del theme. Puede ser el theme, el childtheme, los css que carga o los funcions.php de cualquiera de los 2 que provoquen el problema.
- Luego desactivaría los plugins que contenga la web para ver si es alguno de ellos el que provoca un conflicto con los estilos.

Una vez localizado el origen, se debería buscar una solución adecuada sustituyendo plugins o modificando hojas de estilo.

El link que adjuntas lleva a una web que no es la afectada, por lo que tampoco puedo ayudar más...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a copiar el codigo fuente de la pagina en un editor visual studio code y ejecutarlo en un locahost, para q puedas visualizar la falla.